# How to get checkouted branch after git polling in jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline job polling a git repository each minute.

My job is defined like the following:

```
node {
  git url: 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-scm-step-plugin'
  echo('$BRANCH');
  sh('mvn clean install');
}
```

How to get `$BRANCH` set to the branch actually polled ?

In the logs i can see the branch checked out:

```
10:45:23 Checking out Revision 9053e9aae1fdf548b6b54928305eee59bfe903e7 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
...
10:45:23  > git checkout -b master 9053e9aae1fdf548b6b54928305eee59bfe903e7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Git branch using the `BRANCH_NAME` variable (via `env.BRANCH_NAME`):

```
node {
  git url: 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-scm-step-plugin'
  echo(env.BRANCH_NAME);
  sh('mvn clean install');
}
```

Comment: Weird.. works for me in [this context](https://github.com/TYPO3-infrastructure/jenkins-pipeline-global-library-chefci/blob/7463d28cd2a9c07c1c5192e4421d55e8b56531b4/src/org/typo3/chefci/v1/Pipeline.groovy#L47).